# Cooling of electronic components

Tags: heat

I have built an electronic circuit that connects to a 5V power supply. The power supply does get a bit warm when the circuit is operational. The supply is cooled using air convection method.

Will buying a 12V dc fan help to cool down the supply? If not what can I use that will not break my wallet.

Is there a criterion to follow when selecting an electromechanical cooling system i.e. cooling fan.?

The power supply is a Meanwell RS-15. The circuit pulls about 1.8A.

Comment: A fan would probably help. You could also try putting a larger heatsink on the heat-producing components. Or you could switch to a more efficient power supply.

Comment: @Hearth I cannot alter the supply due to it being bought. Altering it will void the warranty I have on it.

Comment: It would probably help to know more details of your power supply. Is it a switching supply, or linear? How much current are you pulling from it, anyway? Is it a $1 USB charger of questionable origin or a $5000 laboratory-quality bench supply?

Comment: @Hearth The power supply is a Meanwell RS-15. The circuit pulls about 1.8A. It cost about $16

Comment: Shopping is off-topic on this site, but in general 12 VDC fans for PC power supplies are available in a variety of size and power consumption. What research have you done so far?

Comment: How much hot does it get? Does it burn hand under a few seconds or just warm? Did you mount it that the convection is efficient? (Depending on the fins, this when air is able to sweep the fins as much as possible when rising due to being hot air.)

Comment: Warm is fine enough. Even almost too hot to touch. But: Keep air path clear and dust free. Even modest fan circulation will greatly improve heatsink capability. 'Meanwell' are competent. If you are well inside all specs (Von, Vout, Iout temperature, mounting. ) Then it should be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-single-output-enclosed-power-supply-output-rs--15--5

Meanwell claim that this power-supply can produce up to 3A with only free air cooling.

The transformers used in switch-mode powersupplies have an efficiency vs temperature curve that peaks at around 80C, so it's probably supposed to be "a bit warm"

If you still think a fan is needed typical 12V PC cooling fans will operate at 5V (but run slower, and much quieter)

In the data sheet https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/RS-15/RS-15-spec.pdf
Meanwell say at 70 degrees ambient it can provide 60% of its rated power (graph, bottom of page 2). That would be 1.8A which is all you need.

Comment: The environment the supply is located in is also warm. Will adding a fan do any good in terms of cooling?

Comment: Meanwell say it will work up to 70C with free-air (data-sheet page 2, bottom left) https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/RS-15/RS-15-spec.pdf

Comment: It is NOT a good idea to run a 12V fan on 5V. There is no guarantee it will function properly.

Comment: @JackCreasey there is no guarantee, but I would be most interested in any evidence of premature failure when undervolted.

Comment: I did not say it would prematurely fail, simply that it may not work are expected. Here's a Delta datasheet, and notice that it specifies 6-13.8V  http://www.delta-fan.com/Download/Spec/ASB0312HA-AF00.pdf  Corsair fans tend to specify 7-10V as the minimum on their 12V fans, and the widest voltage range I know of is the Arctic fans ….they do specify a 12V fan down to 5V: https://www.arctic.ac/us_en/f8.html ….though from experience I can tell you the perform poorly (cfm) at the lower voltages.

Answer (score 3):

"A bit warm" is not a very useful design criteria (unless you are in biological markets, where this can be an issue).

Too hot to handle can be as little as 45°C, which would barely register for most electronics. Burnt skin starts at around 60°C which is at the low-end temperature of many CPUs in modern computers. Design operational temperatures for power electronics can exceed 100°C.

Higher temperatures do affect lifetimes, [but the effect is exponential](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/dictionary/terms/arrhenius-equation-reliability), so not too much of an issue at the lower end of the range.

"A bit warm" is fine for most designs.

Answer (score 1):

The temperature that your product gets to in its enclosure in free air depends on the airflow around the supply, the circuit and the case. In a sealed container the temperatures could get quite high.

You don't describe how you product is configured, but assuming the load consuming the 5V is in the same case as the power supply:

You thermal load  in watts is about (5V * 2A) * 1.3 = 13W

This is actually very moderate load for this [RS-15-5](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/RS-15/RS-15-spec.pdf) power supply, but your total thermal load (assuming the supply and product are in the same enclosure) is not insignificant at 13W.

[image]

If your enclosure is relatively sealed you would be well advised to add a fan.

I would suggest that a small 5V fan may be appropriate, powered from the 5V supplying your circuit.

**NOTE:** I would NOT suggest the use of a 12V fan on a 5V supply. There is some possibility that the fan may not start when using 5V, whereas a 5V fan is guaranteed to start at 5V. Most small computer fans today are BLDC motors run a by chip. These are typically NOT suitable for voltage control, and may simply not start at lower voltages. Most are equipped to use either PWM, or a speed signal PWM at their rated voltage. Many only guarantee performance at their rated voltage +/-10-15%.

5V fans are typically small; in the 40-60mm square range and readily available.

Here is a pointer to an example low noise, 60mm square with ball bearings ([FAD1-06025](http://www.qualtekusa.com/images/Fans/pdf_files/FAD1-06025-A.pdf)) and a power rating of only 1W (200mA). this would make your total thermal load about 14W.
There are endless varieties of good fans available with various form factors and from various sources. I'd suggest however that you get a ball bearing fan at the slowest speed possible to reduce the noise.